# flow of holomorphic vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, differential-equations

Let $(M,J)$ be a complex manifold, where $J$ is the integrable complex structure. Let $X$ be a holomorphic vector field on $M$ and let $\varphi_{t} : M\rightarrow M   $ be its flow. Question: Is $\varphi_{t}$ a biholomorphism? It is a diffeomorphism but is it holomorphic?

Comment: Yes. The solutions of a holomorphic differential equation are holomorphic. The question would be more appropriate on MSE.

Comment: Can you provide some details or reference?

Comment: Henri Cartan, *Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions of One or Several Complex Variables*, Chap. 7 (Dover Publications). This is the translation of the notes of one of Cartan's undergraduate courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is local, so assume that $M$ is open in $\mathbb C^n$, so that we do not have to deal with the second tangent bundle. Then:
\begin{align*}
\partial_t \phi_t &= X\circ \phi_t
\\
T(\partial_t \phi_t) &= \partial_t T(\phi_t) = TX\circ T(\phi_t)
\\
\partial_t J\circ T(\phi_t) &= J\circ\partial_t T(\phi_t)  = J\circ TX\circ T(\phi_t) = TX\circ J\circ T(\phi_t)
\\
\partial_t T(\phi_t)\circ J &= TX\circ T(\phi_t)\circ J
\end{align*}
so $J\circ T(\phi_t)$ and $T(\phi_t)\circ J$ solve the same equation with the same initial value $\phi_0= Id$, thus they are equal.

Comment: What does $T$ denote?

Comment: If the vector field is "complete" (meaning its solution curves and hence its flow) exist for all complex times t), then for each time t the flow at that time is a biholomorphism.

Comment: On a meta level, I find it tremendously unfortunate that a perfectly valid question like this one, by someone who perhaps has not studied this area very much, needs to be closed off. It smacks of snobbery and elitism in the worst way. I cannot imagine how allowing such questions does any harm to MO in any way.